# How do i remove versions from a section after changing section settings to not store versions?

Tags: sections, entry-versions, reindex

I have a section that i have changed from versioning to switching git off as I do not need them. I have also changed a field adding it as searchable.

In order to reindex search field i tried CLI resave/entries. [section] but go a memory error. It reports 56K entries but there are only 12k.

So i assumed this is the versions. Now I have changed section settings how do i get rid of the versions and resave to index field?

Comment: What do you mean by switching git off? You mean you turned off the revision function for this section? This has nothing to do with git. Also, resave/entries shouldn't save revisions, so it's likely it's finding entries from other sections as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prune revisions using the [`utils/prune-revisions` CLI command](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#utils-prune-revisions). This one takes a `--max-revisions` argument you can set to 0 to prune all revisions.

```bash
php craft utils/prune-revisions --max-revisions=0
```

You can also use `--dry-run` to see what the command would do before actually executing it.

As far as I can tell, this method does not have an option to only prune revisions for a specific section. Might be a useful addition, maybe post this as a feature request in the [discussions section on Github](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions).

Comment: Im still running into memory issues with this task. Even open the entry and saving it doesn't execute and index update so the field is not searchable on

Comment: @joomkit Hm, not sure, maybe resaving all entries is just too much, especially if you have a low memory limit. Maybe try it in multiple batches, you can specify `--limit` and `--offset` parameter for that: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#resave-entries

Comment: DOH perfect that has enabled me to achieve the indexing. Funny it chokes before starting